# How to Read text file that has a number of rule in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a number of Radio Button and  two million rule that are if ... else ... . So my ram is limited and I can't run my project, because I need the more memory, with this situation I've decided that write all of rules in a txt file and after that I'll read it.
so I have a problem, I don't understand how to use from this way to can match them together, when I read txt file, system reads line to line and each line lies on between two quotation mark that its type is string. could you give me suggestion.

Regards,
Mostafa

Comment: What are some of these 2 million rules? What do they look like?

Comment: not sure what those "rules" are exactly, but if they are nothing else than conditions match, you can for every condition create a class `Validator`, say, and every instance save into the binary file (with .NET serialization). Once you start, you read them, construct instance of a type and call a method dynamically at runtime, after drop it. Very vague, but so the question is.

Comment: Can you share the sample rules which you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

My rules are, e.g. IF RADIOBUTTON1.CHECKED==TRUE

MESSEAGEBOX.SHOW("HELLO");

I have 50 condition and accroding to I have 50 states, so 50! is I don' t know, but number of my rules is about 2 milion.
Could you expailn more about sth you said me?
Regards,